# Could I make a constraint on inserting 'if the record is not contained in another table'?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have 3 tables.

```
Table 'number':

| x |
|---|
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |


Table 'group':

| group_id |
|----------|
|     1    |
|     2    |


Table 'number_in_group':

| group_id | x |
|----------|---|
|     1    | 4 |
|     1    | 5 |
|     2    | 4 |
|     2    | 5 |
|     2    | 7 |
```

Could I make a constraint on inserting into table `number_in_group` that x does not exist in table `number`?

If yes, is it a good approach, or better to put this business logic on the backend?

Comment: Foreign key check 'if exist', I want to check 'if does not exist'.

Comment: Use a check constraint. But get your logic straight, because data in both tables could change. What should be done when a new record is created in the table “number”?

Comment: I think that the data is immutable (I'm not sure yet). We could not put a new record to the table "number" if it already exists in the table "number_in_group".

Answer (score 0):

There is no constraint in Postgres that say *make sure something does not exist*, but you can create one - a trigger. In this case you select from `numbers` for  the new value of `x` in `number_in_group`. If it exists then raise an exception. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_06qlbZA))

```
create or replace function not_if_in_numbers() 
   returns trigger 
  language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    if exists 
       (select null 
          from numbers
         where x = new.x
       ) 
    then 
       raise exception 'Invalid value for x (%). Found in numbers table.',new.x::text; 
    end if; 

    return new; 
end; 
$$;

create trigger check_restricted_x_biur
   before insert or update of x 
       on number_in_group
      for each row 
  execute function not_if_in_numbers();
```

You should create a similar trigger for `numbers` selecting from `number_in_group` and throws a corresponding exception. Do not build around the concept of an immutable table. It will not happen.